# why doesn't the variable increase?

Tags: java

I am learning Java, so I understand this is a very simple question, but I still want to understand it.

I want to let my code automatically generate soldiers, and the number automatically increases, but I failed.

**the Soldier.class:**

```java
package com.mayer;
import java.util.Random;
public class Soldier {
    private int number=0;
    private int ATK;
    private int HP;
    Random ra = new Random();
    public Soldier(){
        this.number++;
        this.ATK = ra.nextInt(10)+90;
        this.HP = ra.nextInt(20)+180;
    }
    public void report(){
        System.out.println("number:"+this.number+"\t"+
                "ATK:"+this.ATK+"\t"+
                "HP:"+this.HP);
    }

}
```

**the main.class**

```java
package com.mayer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Soldier[] soldiers = new Soldier[5];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<5){
            soldiers[i] = new Soldier();
            i++;
        }
        for(Soldier sol:soldiers){
            sol.report();
        }
    }
    
}
```

**That's what I get:**

```
number:1    ATK:94  HP:187
number:1    ATK:94  HP:181
number:1    ATK:96  HP:193
number:1    ATK:90  HP:183
number:1    ATK:95  HP:193
```

So you see,each of this number is 1.

Comment: Every soldier is created with a field `int number=0;` that you increase in the constructor to 1. If you want one variable tracking something across multiple instances, you might consider adding a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have added number field which is instance field. It will initialize per instance. You are looking for static type variable. Please check [static into java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> **Instance Variables (Non-Static Fields)** Technically speaking, objects
> store their individual states in "non-static fields", that is, fields
> declared without the static keyword. Non-static fields are also known
> as instance variables because their values are unique to each instance
> of a class (to each object, in other words); the currentSpeed of one
> bicycle is independent from the currentSpeed of another.
>
> **Class Variables (Static Fields)** A class variable is any field declared with the static modifier; this tells the compiler that there
> is exactly one copy of this variable in existence, regardless of how
> many times the class has been instantiated. A field defining the
> number of gears for a particular kind of bicycle could be marked as
> static since conceptually the same number of gears will apply to all
> instances. The code static int numGears = 6; would create such a
> static field. Additionally, the keyword final could be added to
> indicate that the number of gears will never change.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is changed to：

```
public Soldier(int number){
    this.number = number;
    this.ATK = ra.nextInt(10)+90;
    this.HP = ra.nextInt(20)+180;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, each `Soldier` instance has its own separate `number` field which starts with 0. You can use a `static` field to count the instances:

```
public class Soldier {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private int number;
    // other fields left out for clarity

    public Soldier(){
        Soldier.counter++;  // field shared among all Soldier instances
        this.number = counter;  // number belongs to this instance only
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. When you get more advanced, you'll learn that using a static field like this can cause problems in a multi-threaded application. I would instead advise passing the number to the Soldier constructor:

```
public class Soldier {
    private int number;
    // ...

    public Soldier(int number){
        this.number = number;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Soldier[] soldiers = new Soldier[5];
    int i = 0;
    while(i<5){
        soldiers[i] = new Soldier(i);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Soldier.class

- all-uppercase field names tend to be used for constants.. basic fields use headless camel-case.. They should also be descriptive, i.e. you should look at them an it should be apparent what they represent - for example a variable "number" is not a good idea, because it's ambiguous
- Random can be converted to a local variable, no need to keep it on the class level
- The mechanism by which soldiers are assigned IDs should be on a higher level - it can't be *managed* by the soldier object itself, hence the constructor with an argument
- overriding the `toString` method is the traditional way of transforming the object to string for debugging purposes.. also most IDEs can generate it with a press of a button so no space for human error

You will obviously need getters and setters for your variables, if you wish to read or change them from elsewhere, but I don't think that's necessary to post here.

```
private int soldierID;
private int attack;
private int health;

public Soldier(int id){

    this.soldierID = id;

    Random random = new Random();
    this.attack = random.nextInt(10) + 90;
    this.health = random.nextInt(20) + 180;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Soldier{" +
            "soldierID=" + soldierID +
            ", attack=" + attack +
            ", health=" + health +
            '}';
}
```

### Main.class

- it's perfectly fine and actually preferred to use a `List` instead of an array, because it's more comfortable to work with
- this way it's even much easier to add them dynamically and use the iterator for ID
- you can "report" in the creation cycle

This even shortens the method a bit, not that it's that important here.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Soldier> soldiers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        Soldier newSoldier = new Soldier(i);
        soldiers.add(newSoldier);
        System.out.println(newSoldier.toString());
    }
}
```

This way when you define the soldier IDs it's not from within the Soldier class but rather from something that is "observing" all the soldier classes and knows which is which.